# PHP array taking up too much memory

Tags: php, arrays, memory-management, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array. The array itself is fine. My problem is that the script takes up monster amounts of memory, and since I'm running this on my MAMP install on my iBook G4, my computer freezes up. Below is the full script.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10"; 
$result = mysql_query($query);
$posts = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

            $posts[$row["id"]]['post_id'] = $row["id"];
            $posts[$row["id"]]['post_title'] = $row["title"];
            $posts[$row["id"]]['post_text'] = $row["text"];
            $posts[$row["id"]]['post_tags'] = $row["tags"];
            $posts[$row["id"]]['post_category'] = $row["category"];

foreach ($posts as $post) {
   echo $post["post_id"];
}
```

Is there a workaround that still achieves my goal (to export the MySQL query rows to an array)?

-Dylan

Comment: How much memory is being used?  Have you measured using [memory_get_usage](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php)?

Comment: It can't possibly be a problem with a syntax error caused by the missing `}` after the loop which doesn't get reported since error reporting is turned off, can it? :)

Answer (score 1):

If that code is verbatim, copied/pasted directly from your code, one thing that caught my eye (unless I am seeing things) is the absence of the closing '}' for the while loop???

Cheers,
Alex

Comment: Yeah that was my typo. It's there in my code. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 0):

This is strange because you have set the limit of 10 already. Note that you are specifying associative array eg `$row["title"]` while using `mysql_fetch_array` function, add second parameter to it `MYSQL_ASSOC` or use `mysql_fetch_assoc` function instead:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   $posts[$row["id"]]['post_id'] = $row["id"];
   $posts[$row["id"]]['post_title'] = $row["title"];
   $posts[$row["id"]]['post_text'] = $row["text"];
   $posts[$row["id"]]['post_tags'] = $row["tags"];
   $posts[$row["id"]]['post_category'] = $row["category"];
}
```

You might want to use the `array_chunk` function to chunks from array and manipulate those chunks however you want.

Comment: Thanks but it didn't do the job

Comment: It's not an error message - the page just never loads and the httpd process (the MAMP process) goes way up to 28mb and climbing. I have to stop the page load and force quit the process.